# python list of numbers converted to string incorrectly

Tags: python, string, list

For some reason, when I do the code...

```
def encode():
    result2 = []
    print result  
    for x in result:  
        result2 += str(x)  
    print result2
```

I get...

```
[123, 456, 789]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

How do I get it to return `['123', '456', '789']`?

Thanks!

Comment: @JShoe, you can see the edits I made by clicking on the "edited [X time ago]" link above. In this case, I just fixed the formatting; to get properly formatted code blocks, you should indent the lines by four spaces, or select the code and click the `{}` button above the edit box.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even notice!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
result2 = [str(x) for x in result]
```

The reason you are getting what you are getting is the `+=` is doing list concatenation. Since `str(123)` is `'123'`, which can be seen as `['1', '2', '3']`, when you concatenate that to the empty list you get `['1', '2', '3']` (same thing for the other values).

For it to work doing it your way, you'd need:

```
result2.append(str(x)) # instead of result2 += str(x)
```

Comment: Sweet! It worked! ...Why though? What makes it different from what I did?  
 and would `result = [str(x) for x in result]` work? Or does it HAVE to be a new list?

Comment: @JShoe It doesn't have to be a new list... The difference is you used `+=` (see my answer and senderle's).

Comment: @JShoe `+=` is __extend__ not __append__, so it treats whatever you have on the right as a __sequence__ and adds its items individually.

Answer (score 3):

The functional method is to use `list(map(str, lst))`:

```
lst = [123, 456, 789]

res = list(map(str,  lst))

print(res)
# ['123', '456', '789']
```

Performance is slightly better than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you use `+=` on a list, it expects the thing on the other side of the operator to be a list or some other kind of iterable. So you could do this:

```
>>> def encode():
...     result2 = []
...     print result 
...     for x in result: 
...         result2 += [str(x)]
...     print result2
... 
>>> result = [123, 456, 789]
>>> encode()
[123, 456, 789]
['123', '456', '789']
```

But when you do this:

```
result2 += str(x)
```

Python assumes you meant to treat the result of `str(x)` as an iterable, so before extending `result2`, it effectively* converts the string into a list of characters, as in the below example:

```
>>> [list(str(x)) for x in result]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

As [NullUserException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950605/python-list-of-numbers-converted-to-string-incorrectly/6950612#6950612) suggested, a quick way to convert the items in a list is to use a list comprehension. In this case, just remove the `list` call above.

---

*To be precise, it converts the result of `str(x)` to an iterator (as by calling `iter()` -- or, as eryksun pointed out, by calling the the corresponding C API function [PyObject_GetIter](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GetIter), though of course that only applies to cpython). Since iteration over a string is actually iteration over the individual characters in the string, each character gets added to the list separately.

Comment: @eryksun, I suppose I was oversimplifying.

Answer (score -1):

Using map http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map

```
In [2]: input_list = [123, 456, 789]
In [3]: output_list = map(lambda x:str(x), input_list)
In [4]: output_list
Out[5]: ['123', '456', '789']
```