# Python - Automatically create strings

Tags: python, string

This is a basic question but say I have these values:

`620, 480, 303, 200, 120, 450, 120` and I'm creating a data set from them:

`dataset = [620, 480, 303, 200, 120, 450, 120]`, is there any way to automatically turn these values into strings?

So, `dataset = ["620", "480", "303", "200", "120", "450", "120"]` ?

I've been doing the above manually, but once my dataset becomes quite large, it does take up a lot of time doing. I've gone through  the Python Cookbook, and tried to use one of their codes:

```
line = 'asdf fjdk; afed, fjek,asdf, foo'
import re
re.split(r'[;,\s]\s*', line)
```

It doesn't work because I'm using numbers, rather than letters.

**Question:**: Is it possible to automatically turn these numbers into strings? I can't find a similar question to this in the python API.

Comment: Doesn't `dataset = [str(el) for el in dataset]` work?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `re`? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Anyway, you can call `str` or `repr` on anything to get a string representation of it. (Briefly, `str` is a human-readable string; `repr` is a programmer-readable string; for integers, they're identical.)

Comment: As a side note: I mean no offense when saying this, but it'd probably be better if you did more research. Stack Overflow users in general, [expect question askers to have done some research before asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). When I googled your problem ("convert list of numbers to strings python"), the first result that came up was [_python list of numbers converted to string incorrectly_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950605/python-list-of-numbers-converted-to-string-incorrectly).

Comment: @ChristianDean I would agree with you; however, for beginners in general it is hard even finding that right question (*convert numbers*). Note how OP labeled the question "creating strings", which will not get you to duplicate easily. Not to disagree, just as general point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
dataset = [str(i) for i in dataset]
```

Or you can iterate over your list in a loop:

```
new_dataset = []
for i in dataset:
    new_dataset.append(str(i))
```

You can read up on string operations [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks a bunch for that! I'm still quite new to python, so you providing all these links is great help. I've just used your code and it works perfectly!