# Is there any function to convert a list of numbers in a list into a string?

Tags: python-3.x

```
list_a=[362,673,196,452,972]
```

I want to convert this `list_a` into a string

Individually for each index of the `list_a` I'm able to convert to string. For ex: `list_a[0]=str(362)` but i want to convert the list at once.

Comment: [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is one way: `new_list = [str(x) for x in list_a]`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Do you want a new list, or a string "362,673,196,452,972"? That would be `','.join(str(x) for x in list_a)`

Comment: In this case, you can use `",".join([str(x) for x in list_a])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list of numbers converted to string incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950605/python-list-of-numbers-converted-to-string-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

Like Johnny mentions in his comment list comprehension is your friend.

```
list_a=[362,673,196,452,972]
list_b=[str(x) for x in list_a]
print(list_a)
# create new list of strings
print(list_b)
# join to a single string
print(','.join(list_b))
# or use print if you don't want a new list
print(*list_a,sep=',')
```

*output:*

```
[362, 673, 196, 452, 972]
['362', '673', '196', '452', '972']
362,673,196,452,972
362,673,196,452,972
```